# Transaction(s) still alive: How do I find the cause?

Tags: db2, transaction-log

I can tell that something is hogging the transaction log on the DB2 for one of our Websphere Commerce installations. Basically I have a burst of transaction log files that are timestamped 5 days ago. I expect that this means that something was started 5 days ago and its transaction is still active.

How do I debug this issue? All the hints I can find are about increasing the log size, but in this case it would just be a band aid...

EDIT:
Using db2pd as suggested by mustachio I get the output blow. The way I read it whatever issue was hogging the log is now over, as all live transactions report using 0 log space.

Is that correct?

Further, when I check the log directory (see below), there's been no real change since yesterday (see list of log files below). I take that as supporting evidence that the log hogging issue is no longer in effect.

Log file directory contents:

```
 Directory of E:\db2log\BK_PROD

04-10-2013  06:14    <DIR>          .
04-10-2013  06:14    <DIR>          ..
16-12-2012  20:03        16.756.736 S0026878.LOG
28-09-2013  17:52        40.968.192 S0037690.LOG
28-09-2013  17:52        40.968.192 S0037691.LOG
28-09-2013  17:55        40.968.192 S0037692.LOG
28-09-2013  17:56        40.968.192 S0037693.LOG
28-09-2013  17:57        40.968.192 S0037694.LOG
28-09-2013  21:44        40.968.192 S0037695.LOG
28-09-2013  23:11         4.526.080 S0037696.LOG
28-09-2013  23:35        40.968.192 S0037697.LOG
04-10-2013  06:14        40.968.192 S0037900.LOG
04-10-2013  06:04        40.968.192 S0037901.LOG
04-10-2013  06:04        40.968.192 S0037902.LOG
04-10-2013  06:05        40.968.192 S0037903.LOG
04-10-2013  06:06        40.968.192 S0037904.LOG
04-10-2013  06:07        40.968.192 S0037905.LOG
04-10-2013  06:08        40.968.192 S0037906.LOG
04-10-2013  06:09        40.968.192 S0037907.LOG
04-10-2013  06:10        40.968.192 S0037908.LOG
04-10-2013  06:12        40.968.192 S0037909.LOG
04-10-2013  06:13        40.968.192 S0037910.LOG
04-10-2013  06:14        40.968.192 S0037911.LOG
10-07-2013  13:55               512 SQLLPATH.TAG
              22 File(s)    799.678.976 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  18.659.753.984 bytes free
```

Output from db2pd:

```
Database Partition 0 -- Database BK_PROD -- Active -- Up 85 days 18:10:58 -- Date 10/04/2013 08:06:25

Transactions:
Address            AppHandl [nod-index] TranHdl    Locks      State   Tflag      Tflag2     Firstlsn           Lastlsn            SpaceReserved   LogSpace        TID            AxRegCnt   GXID     ClientUserID                   ClientWrkstnName               ClientApplName                 ClientAccntng                  
0x000007FFF935FF00 7189     [000-07189] 3          0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006BFFDC579 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9360E00 6536     [000-06536] 4          0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F7169 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9361D00 8434     [000-08434] 5          0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD534 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9362C00 5356     [000-05356] 6          0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F71BB 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9363B00 7769     [000-07769] 7          0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD536 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9364A00 6860     [000-06860] 8          0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD537 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9365900 49089    [000-49089] 9          0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD538 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9366800 5929     [000-05929] 10         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD539 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9367700 5501     [000-05501] 11         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD53A 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9368600 6206     [000-06206] 12         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD53B 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9369500 7663     [000-07663] 13         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD53C 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF936A400 7083     [000-07083] 14         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD53D 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF936B300 5350     [000-05350] 15         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006AD6FD540 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            db2evml_DB2DETAILDEADLOCK      n/a                            
0x000007FFF936C200 20935    [000-20935] 16         1          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F78D9 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF936D100 42140    [000-42140] 17         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006BFE59045 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF936FE00 23187    [000-23187] 20         1          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F7928 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9373A00 41407    [000-41407] 24         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F7932 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9375800 59734    [000-59734] 26         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F793B 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9376700 11757    [000-11757] 27         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F7645 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9377600 22364    [000-22364] 28         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F78D8 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9379400 13091    [000-13091] 30         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006BF782A75 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF937A300 54834    [000-54834] 31         1          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F791B 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF937C100 23530    [000-23530] 33         1          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F792B 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF937D000 5248     [000-05248] 34         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F792F 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF937DF00 60862    [000-60862] 35         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F78D7 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF937EE00 26210    [000-26210] 36         1          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F7926 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9380C00 38911    [000-38911] 38         1          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F791A 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9387500 20973    [000-20973] 45         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F77E2 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF9388400 35066    [000-35066] 46         3          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00F793F 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF938A200 10119    [000-10119] 48         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006BFB0556F 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            
0x000007FFF938CF00 4945     [000-04945] 51         0          READ    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0               0               0x0006C00ED6D5 1          0        n/a                            s-bkweb02-f                    n/a                            n/a
```

Comment: _"this means that something was started 5 days ago and its transaction is still active"_ -- No, it does not mean that at all. It means that five days ago there was an activity that generated more than usual volume of logs, that's all.

Comment: OK. I was under the impression that the transaction log only contained records of active transactions, not records of old, completed transactions.

Comment: Which OS are you talking about? DB2 and WebSphere run on several platforms. Your solution will likely be platform dependent.

Comment: Running on Windows.

Comment: @mustaccio So the reason the log files are still around in the directory is that these are the primary log space, and they are pre-allocated?

Comment: Primary logs are pre-allocated, yes, but those files in the log directory are not necessarily primary or active. you can use `db2pd -logs` to see what they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of DB2 on Linux, Unix, or Windows (LUW), you can use the **db2pd** tool to view all current transactions and how much log space they use (the *LogSpace* column):

```
$ db2pd -d tst1 -transactions

Database Member 0 -- Database TST1 -- Active -- Up 3 days 00:34:56 -- Date 2013-10-03-10.19.08.041274

Transactions:
Address            AppHandl [nod-index] TranHdl    Locks      State   Tflag      Tflag2     Firstlsn           Lastlsn            Firstlso             Lastlso              SpaceReserved   LogSpace        TID            AxRegCnt   GXID     ClientUserID                   ClientWrkstnName               ClientApplName                 ClientAccntng                  
...
0x00007F05AE48CA80 17       [000-00017] 686        5          WRITE   0x00000000 0x00000000 0x000000000007BF73 0x000000000007BF75 103504642            103504834            328             616             0x00000000F64C 1          0        n/a                            n/a                            n/a                            n/a
```